# SELECT FROM 2 different tables using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Last time I was able to combined 3 different SELECT queries since it was from the same table. Now, I'm trying to execute a query where in the info was from 2 different tables.

Here's my query string

```
SELECT applicantinfo.FirstName, 
       applicantinfo.MiddleName, 
       applicantinfo.LastName, 
       applicantaccess.ApplicantExamPassword 
  FROM applicantinfo 
  LEFT JOIN applicantaccess WHERE applicantaccess.ApplicantID = '" & lblID.Text & "'"
```

using myphpadmin to test this query and replacing the `lblID.text` with a value, Instead of showing up a singe result, it shows 2 rows.

Here's what it looks like
[image]

I think I miss used using the INNER JOIN keyword here.

My expected output should only be the first row.

*note
Jaranilla's ID should be '201458971' and password is 6zo93ie82m

lopez's ID should be '201437095' and password is 4ew93fo86t

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which properties constitute the join, assuming that "id" is the common attribute, e.g.

```
SELECT applicantinfo.FirstName, applicantaccess.ApplicantExamPassword FROM applicantinfo LEFT JOIN applicantaccess ON applicantinfo.id = applicantaccess.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

In join put condition on which you want to join both tables, try following appID is you primary key and fk_appID is foregin key.

```
SELECT applicantinfo.FirstName, applicantinfo.MiddleName, applicantinfo.LastName, applicantaccess.ApplicantExamPassword 
        FROM applicantinfo  as ainfo
    LEFT JOIN applicantaccess as aa on ainfo.appID = aa.fk_appID
     WHERE applicantaccess.ApplicantID = '" & lblID.Text & "'"
```